# && not working and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

This example works but gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined"

but does not work with && property for two if statement

if(x == true) && if(j=="correct")

```js
 function myFunction(){

  var question = document.getElementById("question-1");
  var options = question.getElementsByTagName("input");
  
  for(var i=0;i<=options.length;i++){
   
   var x = options[i].checked;
   var j = options[i].className;
      // if(x == true) && if(j=="correct"){ - this does not work
   if(x == true){
    if(j=="correct"){
     question.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = "Your answer is correct"; 
    }else{
     question.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = "Your answer is wrong"; 
    }
   }  
  }
 };
```

```html
 <ul>
  <div id="question-1">
   <li>What is a Computer Bug?</li>
   <input type="radio" name="selection" class="correct" onclick="myFunction()"><label>An error</label>
   <input type="radio" name="selection" class="wrong" onclick="myFunction()"><label>A Moth</label> 
   <p class="result"></p>
  </div>
 </ul>
```

Comment: that's not how && work with ifs. it should be if(x == true && j == "correct")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `i< options.length` instead of `i<=options.length` Because options.length is 2. if you use `=<` then it it will iterate up to `2<=2` so you 2 is undefined.

```js
function myFunction(){

  var question = document.getElementById("question-1");
  var options = question.getElementsByTagName("input");
 
  for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
   
   var x = options[i].checked;
   var j = options[i].className;
      // if(x == true) && if(j=="correct"){ - this does not work
   if(x == true){
    if(j=="correct"){
     question.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = "Your answer is correct"; 
    }else{
     question.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = "Your answer is wrong"; 
    }
   }  
  }
 };
```

```html
<ul>
  <div id="question-1">
   <li>What is a Computer Bug?</li>
   <input type="radio" name="selection" class="correct" onclick="myFunction()"><label>An error</label>
   <input type="radio" name="selection" class="wrong" onclick="myFunction()"><label>A Moth</label> 
   <p class="result"></p>
  </div>
 </ul>
```

Comment: glad to help you.